# Newbie dealing with char using malloc

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm doing USART with a ring/circular buffer. Having trouble moving the chars in the Buffer to this `char* Command_String` that I defined:

```
char holder ;
holder = usart_getchar();
RingBuffer_Insert(&Buffer, holder);

if (holder == '\0') {
  uint16_t BufferCount = RingBuffer_GetCount(&Buffer);
  char* Command_String = malloc (BufferCount);
  while (BufferCount--) {
    *Command_String = RingBuffer_Remove(&Buffer);
    Command_String++;                 
  }
  usart_pstr(Command_String);
  free (Command_String);
}
```

The functions `RingBuffer_Insert()` and `RingBuffer_GetCount()` work. But my attempt to move the chars to `Command_String` doesn't. Help plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You increment the Command_String pointer:

```
while (BufferCount--) {
*Command_String = RingBuffer_Remove(&Buffer);
Command_String++;                 
             }
```

But then use it as if it still points at the start:

```
usart_pstr(Command_String);
 free (Command_String);
```

You should take a copy of it for filling the string, so you retain the original value for future use, or else index it without modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're incrementing Command_String with

```
Command_String++;
```

By the time your loop finishes, Command_String is pointing to it's last char.